# Cocoa - customize help menu item

Tags: cocoa, macos

I need to open safari to the help event in my cocoa application. We can customize the help menu item as this.

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000072.php

But I need to open the the browser to this event. Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change the action of that menu item to another one you provide that opens the web browser with `-[NSWorkspace openURL:]`.

Comment: To change the action of the help menu item, you can override `- (void)showHelp:(id)sender`.

Answer (score 9):

exactly:

```
- (void)showHelp:(id)sender
{
    NSURL * helpFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"help" withExtension:@"html"];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:helpFile];
}
```